# How to round off to the closest 5 minute interval if it is 1 or 2 minutes ahead or behind?

Tags: java, java-8, localdatetime

I want to round off an Instant / LocalDateTime to its closest 5 minutes interval in Java.

**Examples:**
*Suppose the time is:* 2021-02-08T19:**02**:49.594
*Expected result:* 2021-02-08T19:**00**:00.000

*Suppose the time is:* 2021-02-08T19:**03**:49.594
*Expected result:* 2021-02-08T19:**05**:00.000

*Similarly, if the time is:* 2021-02-08T19:**56**:49.594
*Expected result:* 2021-02-08T19:**55**:00.000

*Similarly, if the time is:* 2021-02-08T19:**58**:49.594
*Expected result:* 2021-02-08T20:**00**:00.000

> But if the time is 2021-02-08T19:**55**:00.000 or
> 2021-02-08T19:**05**:00.000 or 2021-02-08T19:**00**:00.000 then do
> nothing.

Comment: Use an external clock as reference.

Comment: `2021-02-08T19:05:00.000` is the closest 5-min stop to `2021-02-08T19:02:49.594` (because the seconds are past 30). What's your logic for wanting 19:00?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a general-purpose solution (not just 5 minutes):

```
public static Instant toNearest(Duration interval, Instant instant) {
    long intervalMillis = interval.toMillis();
    long adjustedInstantMillis = (instant.toEpochMilli() + (intervalMillis / 2)) / intervalMillis * intervalMillis;
    return Instant.ofEpochMilli(adjustedInstantMillis);
}

public static LocalDateTime toNearest(Duration interval, LocalDateTime dateTime, ZoneId zoneId) {
    ZoneRules zoneRules = zoneId.getRules();
    Instant instant = toNearest(interval, dateTime.toInstant(zoneRules.getOffset(dateTime)));
    return LocalDateTime.ofInstant(instant, zoneRules.getOffset(instant));
}

public static LocalDateTime toNearest(Duration interval, LocalDateTime dateTime) {
    return toNearest(interval, dateTime, ZoneId.systemDefault());
}

@Test
public void toNearestRoundsCorrectly() {
    assertThat(toNearest(Duration.ofMinutes(5), LocalDateTime.of(2021, 2, 8, 19, 0, 0)))
            .isEqualTo(LocalDateTime.of(2021, 2, 8, 19, 0, 0));
    assertThat(toNearest(Duration.ofMinutes(5), LocalDateTime.of(2021, 2, 8, 19, 2, 29, 999999999)))
            .isEqualTo(LocalDateTime.of(2021, 2, 8, 19, 0, 0));
    assertThat(toNearest(Duration.ofMinutes(5), LocalDateTime.of(2021, 2, 8, 19, 2, 30)))
            .isEqualTo(LocalDateTime.of(2021, 2, 8, 19, 5, 0));
    assertThat(toNearest(Duration.ofMinutes(5), LocalDateTime.of(2021, 2, 8, 19, 5, 0)))
            .isEqualTo(LocalDateTime.of(2021, 2, 8, 19, 5, 0));
}

@Test
public void toNearestTreatsDaylightSavingChangesCorrectly() {
    assertThat(toNearest(Duration.ofMinutes(5), LocalDateTime.of(2021,3,27, 23,57,30), ZoneId.of("Europe/London")))
            .isEqualTo(LocalDateTime.of(2021,3,28, 0,0,0));
    assertThat(toNearest(Duration.ofMinutes(5), LocalDateTime.of(2021,3,28, 0,57,29,999999999), ZoneId.of("Europe/London")))
            .isEqualTo(LocalDateTime.of(2021,3,28, 0,55,0));
    assertThat(toNearest(Duration.ofMinutes(5), LocalDateTime.of(2021,3,28, 0,57,30), ZoneId.of("Europe/London")))
            .isEqualTo(LocalDateTime.of(2021,3,28, 2,0,0));
    assertThat(toNearest(Duration.ofMinutes(5), LocalDateTime.of(2021,3,28, 2,5,0), ZoneId.of("Europe/London")))
            .isEqualTo(LocalDateTime.of(2021,3,28, 2,5,0));
}
```

Comment: first of all, thanks for your effort .got the desired output. 
    Is there any way that I can round off to the time 5 minutes earlier only?
    e.g: 2021-02-08T19:26:49.594, 2021-02-08T19:27:49.594. 2021-02-08T19:28:49.594, 2021-02-08T19:29:49.594
    Expected result: 2021-02-08T19:25:00.000

Comment: Yes, just replace the 3rd line above with `long adjustedInstantMillis = instant.toEpochMilli() / intervalMillis * intervalMillis;` (i.e. remove the addition of the half-interval)

Comment: Thanks, can you please explain this line of logic in a simple one liner..

Comment: It relies on integer division. When using an integral data type such as `int` or `long`, the expression `a / b * b` is equivalent to `truncate(a / b) * b` (assuming there is a method called truncate which removes the fractional part). So `a/b*b` results in a value that is a to the nearest multiple of b which is equal to or less than a. (It gets a bit more complicated with negative numbers, so dates earlier than 1970, which give a negative value of epochMilli, might not be correct.)

Answer (score 0):

This code gives examples for both Instant and LocalDatetime.

```
        Instant instant = Instant.now();
        long instantLong = instant.toEpochMilli();
        long roundedEpochMilli = (instantLong/(60*5*1000) )  * 60 * 5 *1000; 
        if((instantLong % (60*5*1000))> (30*5*1000))
             roundedEpochMill += 60*5*1000;
        Instant instantRounded = Instant.ofEpochMilli(roundedEpochMilli);
        System.out.println("instant "+ instant +" -- "+ instantRounded);
        
        LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
        ZoneId systemZone = ZoneId.systemDefault(); // my timezone
        ZoneOffset currentOffsetForMyZone = systemZone.getRules().getOffset(instant);
        long nowLong = now.toEpochSecond(currentOffsetForMyZone);
        long roundedEpochSecond = (nowLong/(60*5) )  * 60 * 5; 
        if((nowLong % (60*5))> (30*5))
             roundedEpochSecond += 60*5;
        LocalDateTime nowRounded = LocalDateTime.ofEpochSecond(roundedEpochSecond, 0, currentOffsetForMyZone);
        System.out.println("now "+ instant +" -- "+ nowRounded);
```

Answer (score 0):

this should round it accordingly:

```java
        long min5 = 1000 * 60 * 5;
        String time = "2021-02-08T19:56:49.594";
        time = time.replace("T", " "); // cannot deal with T
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-dd-MM HH:mm:ss.SSS");
        try{
            Date dt = format.parse(time);
            long t = dt.getTime();
            long d = t %min5;
            if(d > min5/2) { // round up
                t += min5 - d;
            } else { // round down
                t -= d;
            }
            System.out.println(format.format(new Date(t)));
        }catch(ParseException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```